# How to typeset a symbol for "the inside of a triangle"?

Tags: support, mathjax

I'd like to use a symbol to denote *the inside of a triangle* inside mathematical formulas in an answer I'm writing for Mathematics Stack Exchange.

A natural candidate is a triangle with a dot inside it: ◬. How can I typeset this symbol in MathJax?

It's available in Unicode at code point U+25EC, however when I use the unicode symbol inside a MathJax formula, the symbol's size is considerably smaller than the normal symbol for a triangle whose command is `\triangle`: `$\unicode{x25ec}$` typesets as $\unicode{x25ec}$ whereas `$\triangle$` typesets as $\triangle$. I'd like the dotted triangle to have the same size as the symbol that is typeset by the command `\triangle`.

The dotted triangle symbol is also available as the command `\trianglecdot` of the LaTeX package `stix`, but I don't know how to import this package to a Mathematics Stack Exchange answer, and even if I could, it would likely simply resolve to the above-mentioned unicode symbol.

I'm also open to suggestions of alternative symbols.

Comment: Try [overlaying symbols](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/32210/1072645).

Comment: On my computer, the two triangles $◬$ and $\triangle$ are about the same size, even in different math renderers html-css: https://i.stack.imgur.com/AbTs2.png and common html: https://i.stack.imgur.com/asRvV.png . Of course this is because the unicode symbol used depends on the fonts installed

Comment: On the suggestion front, you could consider that `\mathring A`$\mathring A$ is used to denote the topological interior of a set $A$, so why not `\mathring\triangle`$\mathring\triangle$?

Comment: $\text{int}(\triangle)$ seems best to me as $\text{int}(S)$ is a classical notation for interior of a set. (command is ´\text{int}(\triangle))´)

Answer (score 3):

Expanding on Be Kind's comment above.

You can use the `\rlap` command to overlay one character on another:
`$\rlap{\,\,\cdot}\triangle$` gives $\rlap{\,\,\cdot}\triangle$

I'm not sure how or if it scales, but `$\large \rlap{\,\,\cdot}\triangle$` does make it bigger: $\large \rlap{\,\,\cdot}\triangle$

The `\,`s are used to create space so the dot moves to the right. You can experiment with different spacings until the dot appears centered in the triangle.

Comment: The precise amount of left/right spacing needed is unfortunately device dependent; see for instance [Why does MathJax render differently on different devices?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/34967/) This is not a new problem, but I have discovered a new way to overlap, which trades the horizontal inaccuracy for vertical inaccuracy; sometimes better.`\overset{\cdot}{\smash\triangle}`$\overset{\cdot}{\smash\triangle}$. See also $\overset{\bullet}{\smash\triangle}\overset{\circ}{\smash\triangle}\overset{\blacksquare}{\smash\triangle}\overset{\blacktriangle}{\smash\triangle}$

Answer (score 2):

A possible alternative symbol: a black triangle. `$\blacktriangle$` typesets as $\blacktriangle$. Compare the black triangle with the triangle that is typeset by `\triangle`: $\blacktriangle\ \triangle$. Its size can be enlarged with `\large` thus: ${\large\blacktriangle}\ \triangle$.

Answer (score 2):

I would like to suggest something for the

> I'm also open to suggestions of alternative symbols.

$\text{int}(\triangle)$ seems good to me as $\text{int}(S)$ is a classical notation for interior of a set. Command is `\text{int}(\triangle))`

Actually, IMHO, mathematically best is:

Let $T$ be a triangle and let $\text{int}(T)$ denote its interior with respect to the Euclidean topology.

Comment: $\DeclareMathOperator{\intt}{int}$If the operator is being used many times in the post, one can also write `$\DeclareMathOperator{\intt}{int}$` at the start of the post, and then just use `$\intt(\triangle)$`. This will produce the same output: $\intt(\triangle)$.

Comment: Thanks. This is not adequate for my purposes, since in my use case the triangle symbol is used in the standard way it is used in geometry as an operator not a set, thus: $\triangle ABC$ for the triangle with vertices $A$, $B$, and $C$.

Comment: it seems that the natural suggestion would then be $\operatorname{int}(\triangle ABC)$.

Answer (score 0):

`$\triangle\hspace{-7pt}\bullet$`

$$\triangle\hspace{-7pt}\bullet$$