# Why does MathJax render differently on different devices?

Tags: bug, mathjax

On my laptop (macOS), `$$\mathbin{\rlap{\,\,\bullet}\triangle}$$` renders as

[image]

On my phone (Android), however, the same code (i.e. `$$\mathbin{\rlap{\,\,\bullet}\triangle}$$`) renders as
[image]

*(Note that the size difference is because of the difference in image size, not because of MathJax.)*

> Why does MathJax render differently on different devices? Is this a MathJax bug, an SE bug or a local bug, and is there a way to fix it?

You can check what it looks like here in this post for you: $$\mathbin{\rlap{\,\,\bullet}\triangle}$$

**Edit:** It seems that the rendering is different on my laptop and phone only when using the HTML-CSS renderer.

Comment: I have included the MathJax formula directly in this post - so that others can see how this displays to them. I hope that's ok. (I have tried [various MathJax rendererers](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/30859) on the same device - but I did not notice a substantial difference between the renderers. only Preview HTML looks rather different from the other ones.)

Comment: On your phone, which is likely an iphone, the XITS fonts are installed and this is the default (common HTML renderer). You can change the behavior as in the above post

Comment: @MartinSleziak Sure. Calvin, what is strange is that both my phone and laptop use the HTML-CSS renderer, but still produce different outputs. Also, I'm on an Android.

Comment: Well...that's news to me then! In any case, the output is virtually identical to your phone on my mac, and also on my iphone, when using the common HTML renderer.

Comment: What happens if you change the renderer on your phone? IIRC It is *supposed* to specifically *not* use XITS in one of them

Comment: @CalvinKhor It seems that the output on my phone and laptop are virtually identical on every renderer except the HTML-CSS renderer.

Comment: My first comment had a typo because I misremembered. On Macs/iOS devices, the HTML-CSS renderer uses the XITS font.

Comment: @CalvinKhor That pretty much solves it, I guess.